# Numerical radius and norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

Let $u,v$ be the unit vectors and $A\in\mathscr{B(\mathscr{H})}$. Is the following inequality true
$$\vert\langle Au,v\rangle\vert\leq \frac{w(A)}{\vert\langle u,v\rangle\vert}$$
where $w(A):=\sup\limits_{\Vert f\Vert=1}\vert\langle Af,f\rangle\vert$ is the numerical radius of A

---

Comments: First note that if $0\leq\vert\langle u,v\rangle\vert\leq\frac{1}{2}$, the inequality follows as $\Vert A\Vert\leq 2w(A)$. The inequality also follows if $\vert\langle u,v\rangle\vert=1$. But I could neither to prove the inequality for $\frac{1}{2}<\vert\langle u,v\rangle\vert<1$ nor find a counter example to disprove it.

Any comment/hint is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can $|\langle u,v\rangle|\in[0,1/2]$ and $|\langle u,v\rangle|=1$ at the same time?

Comment: Your inequality is seriously flawed.  Just think of what  happens if you multiply $u$ by a large constant.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Sorry, I will edit there. I wanted to mean there if $\vert\langle u,v\rangle\vert\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, the inequality follows. Also if $\vert\langle u,v\rangle\vert=1$, the inequality follows. One needs to check it for $\vert\langle u,v\rangle\vert \in(\frac{1}{2},1)$.

Comment: @Ruy note that the inequality is being guessed for unit vectors $u,v$. So, if I understood you correctly, the argument which you said will not be applicable here to get a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry @Piku, you are right!  Nevertheless I think it is a bit awkard to have $u$ and $v$ on the denominator on the RHS, but I suppose you must have your reasons to conjecture this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality does not hold in general. Let $H=\mathbb C^2$,
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad u=\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\ \sqrt3/2\end{bmatrix},\qquad v=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt3/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\omega(A)=1/2$,
$$
\langle Au,v\rangle=\frac{\sqrt3}2\frac{\sqrt3}2=\frac34,
$$
$$
\langle u,v\rangle=\frac{\sqrt3}2,
$$
and
$$
\frac{\omega(A)}{\langle u,v\rangle}=\frac{1/2}{\sqrt3/2}=\frac1{\sqrt3}<\frac34=\langle Au,v\rangle.
$$

Comment: I had played taking $A=E_{12}$ but unfortunately could not conclude as I took $u=e_1$. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: What I did was to take $u=(t,\sqrt{1-t^2})$, $v=(s,\sqrt{1-s^2})$, write $\langle A u,v\rangle\,\langle u,v\rangle$ as a function on $t$ and $s$, and find the max using calculus.

Comment: I should have thought more before posting it here. Thank you sir for all your help.

Comment: No need to feel bad about it. Often times the very act of posting a question will help you in your thinking about the problem. I have way more regrets about **not** asking something than about asking.